# php get variable $_get

Tags: php, get

**userfile.php:**

```
<form action="userrename.php" method="get">
      <input type="hidden" name="rename" value="<?= $filecode?>">
      <input type="submit" name="rename" id="bdelete" value="Rename"><br><br>
</form>
```

When I click rename button it is get: `userrename.php?rename=pev8nERsJolwrCHyfQZujI1QHMDQHQX6V0ZMtQhsDi1aRgPeJsR&rename=rename`

**username.php:**

```
<?php 
if(empty($_GET['rename'])) 
    echo "No GET variables"; 
else 
    echo $_GET['rename']; //here result is : rename
?>
```

I must get only this `pev8nERsJolwrCHyfQZujI1QHMDQHQX6V0ZMtQhsDi1aRgPeJsR` not `rename` in if statement. How I can do that any one has idei or know I am confused about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following to have the filecode in GET and the rename value in POST:

```
<form action="userrename.php?rename=<?= $filecode?>" method="POST">
     <input type="submit" name="rename" id="bdelete" value="Rename"><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: The reason the value is not coming through is that the hidden input and the submit button have the same name! You are circumventing it by creating both a GET and a POST value of the same name - that's not good! Especially if the name of the submit button doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

remove name of

```
<input type="submit" name="rename" id="bdelete" value="Rename">
```

or change its name to name="xxxx"

Answer (score 1):

Both your input for elements use same name (name="rename"), easiest solution is to change name of your submit input. If you have only 1 submit button on your form you can just remove the name attribute completely. Only elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form, so if you remove it it is still a valid HTML and it's value won't be submitted..